# fabric.js, create some shapes on contextTop

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

This is a question about fabric.js. I have been trying to create some shapes on the contextTop. When you create some shapes on contextTop(not using `add`), how to merge them with the fabric.js canvas?

```
let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('C');
canvas.contextTop.StrokeRect(12,12,30,30);
```

Then, I want to make the Rect appear on the canvas. What should I do? Could anybody tell me how to use canvas API in fabric.js?

I do not understand contextTop, contextContainer...

Comment: Have a look at basic fabric.js examples and use the fabric.js api to create shapes. This will add shapes to the fabric.js canvas, fabric.js will know about and track all the objects on its own canvas. this is how its works, Dont try use your own html5 canvas and merge.

Comment: no, I want to know how it works, not simply use it, sir

Comment: There are many example and tutorials on the the web as well as documentation which will explain "how" it works. Stack Overflow is for users who have tried to and failed to get something working, who post the issue and what they have tried to ask for help on specific problems. Questions that are too broad might get closed. Reading the documentation, and looking for fabric.js tutorials online first will help you a lot.

Comment: What should I do to show the specific rect on a fabric canvas?https://codepen.io/kangax/pen/lpAnD, like freedrawingBrush

Comment: in fabricjs free drawing brushes [availabale](http://fabricjs.com/freedrawing), you can use that. and some [tutorial](http://fabricjs.com/articles/)

Comment: Can u show me a case?like this one,codepen.io/kangax/pen/lpAnD,not in tutorial(by fabric canvas)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use canvas API directly.
FabricJS is a framework to work on the canvas and you have to use the framework rules, or it will break.

ContextTop is the result of getContext('2d') from the upperCanvas, where the upperCanvas is a canvas layered on top of the main one to do some quick drawing that does not require full canvas refresh.

All the html5 canvas drawing that are done outside the provided API  will be wiped at the next frame.

To draw a rect you have to create the rect class and add it to the canvas, that is the correct way to do it:

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({ width: 200, height: 300 });
canvas.add(rect);
```

Comment: so, same question, how can I figure out https://codepen.io/kangax/pen/lpAnD on a fabric js